# corrupted double-linked list on free()

Tags: c, malloc, free, calloc

I successfully run my code in small data but when i tried large scaled data, it gives me

> "corrupted double-linked list:"

In small data, if I delete free() functions, error is disappeared and code works, but in large data whether i put free or not, code gives this error.

Creation of malloc and using free in my code as follows,

```
int **msgcount = malloc(partnum*sizeof(int*));
for(i=0; i<partnum; i++)
    msgcount[i] = malloc( partnum*sizeof(int));

...lots of code

for(i=0;i<partnum;i++)
{
   free(msgcount[i]);
}
```

Comment: "...lots of code" has the key of your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This message comes from glibc and means that you faced a memory corruption or you doubly freed the same pointer. Try to run under valgrind and find where's the corruption occurred.